# Values don't get added into the right place Json Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to create a json file that I keep adding values to it but i'm facing an issue which is the values that I'm adding aren't going to where i want them to go.
this code should help to make my issue a bit clear:

this is how I want the json to look like:

```
{
"Questions":[
    {
        "text": "text",
        "c1": "text",
        "c2": "text",  // #########################################
        "c3": "text",  // This is what i want the json to look like
        "c4": "text",  // #########################################
        "answer": 1,
        "way": "text",
        "isImage": true,
        "imagePath": "path"
    }
]
```

}

and this is how it end up looking like:

```
{
"Questions": [
    {}
],
"text": "text",
"c1": "text",
"c2": "text",
"c3": "text", // #########################################
"c4": "text", // This is how it get generated by the code
"answer": 1,  //##########################################
"way": "text",
"isImage": true,
"imagePath": "path"
```

}

and this is the code that I use to append the new values
```

```
new_data = {"text": self.question_line.toPlainText(),
         "c1": self.c1_line.toPlainText(),
         "c2": self.c2_line.toPlainText(),
         "c3": self.c3_line.toPlainText(),
         "c4": self.c4_line.toPlainText(),
         "answer": self.answer,
         "way": self.answer_line.toPlainText(),
         "isImage": self.isImage_check.isChecked(),
         "imagePath": self.image_path_line.text(),
        }

with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
     file_data = json.load(file)
     file.seek(0)
     file_data.update(new_data)
     json.dump(file_data, file, indent= 4)
```

```
This code that I'm using its from this [guide][1]


> Example 2: Updating a JSON file. Suppose the json file looks like this.
> 
>
>[Picture 1 Example][2]
>
>We want to add another json data after emp_details. Below is the implementation.
> 
> 
> 
>     # Python program to update
>     # JSON
>     
>     import json
>      
>      
>     # function to add to JSON
>     def write_json(new_data, filename='data.json'):
>         with open(filename,'r+') as file:
>               # First we load existing data into a dict.
>             file_data = json.load(file)
>             # Join new_dat3a with file_data
>             file_data.update(new_data)
>             # Sets file's current position at offset.
>             file.seek(0)
>             # convert back to json.
>             json.dump(file_data, file, indent = 4)
>      
>         # python object to be appended
>     y = {"emp_name":'Nikhil',
>          "email": "nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org",
>          "job_profile": "Full Time"
>         }
>          
>     write_json(y)
> 
> Output:  [Picture 2 Output][3]



which is supposed to do the same thing that i want but for some reason it doesn't

Thank you for your time.

  [1]: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-to-json-file-using-python/
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjegx.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZYK5.png
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the formatting miss i don't know how to properly format the question :(

Comment: `file_data["Questions"].append(new_data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Questions" value is a list, you should append the json that your willing to add to the json you have.

check this out:

```py
json_obj = {
  "Questions":[

]
}

new_data = {
         "text": self.question_line.toPlainText(),
         "c1": self.c1_line.toPlainText(),
         "c2": self.c2_line.toPlainText(),
         "c3": self.c3_line.toPlainText(),
         "c4": self.c4_line.toPlainText(),
         "answer": self.answer,
         "way": self.answer_line.toPlainText(),
         "isImage": self.isImage_check.isChecked(),
         "imagePath": self.image_path_line.text(),
        }

data = json_obj["Questions"].append(new_data)
json_obj["Questions"] = data
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python

Basically all you missed was the data['Questions'] = [] I believe, this caused the weird issue.

```
import json

data = {}
data['Questions'] = []
data['Questions'].append({
    "text": self.question_line.toPlainText(),
    "c1": self.c1_line.toPlainText(),
    "c2": self.c2_line.toPlainText(),
    "c3": self.c3_line.toPlainText(),
    "c4": self.c4_line.toPlainText(),
    "answer": self.answer,
    "way": self.answer_line.toPlainText(),
    "isImage": self.isImage_check.isChecked(),
    "imagePath": self.image_path_line.text(),
})


with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

end result:

```
{
  "Questions": [
    {
      "text": "test",
      "c1": "test",
      "c2": "test",
      "c3": "test",
      "c4": "test",
      "answer": "test",
      "way": "test",
      "isImage": "test",
      "imagePath": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tested this with simulated data, and it worked fine, but let me know if you have any issues with it